# My css in jquery does not work codeigniter

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, codeigniter

when i write like this

```
function go(){
    alert("ok");
    $('#content').css("color","red");
    alert("good");
}
```

it prints "ok" but do not change css and does not print "good". This is my Jquery file.

```
<div id = "content">
    <a class="left-side1" href="http://localhost/codeigniter/index.php/project/main" onClick="go();">Some Text</a>
</div>
```

and there i'm calling function go()

May you help me please

Comment: Have you added the jQuery library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are changing the container not the link color. Change your code to the following. It prints "ok" and crashes after because you do not have the jquery library included. Include the library by the following, and then change your javascript as given below.

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
function go(){
    alert("ok");
    $('#content a').css("color","red");
    alert("good");
    return false;
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Code looks ok.

Perhaps you need to include the jQuery library before your script?

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the jQuery click event like below.

```
$("#content a").click(function(event) {

  event.preventDefault();
  $("#content a").css("color","red");

});
```

The `preventDefault();` is there to cancel the default link action.

Preventing the default action will mean that the link dosen't work anymore, if you want to change the link colour after its been clicked and the page is re-loaded then you will need to use a different method.

Comment: No worries, don't forget to +1 if you find things helpful.